# Python: Can't display images in Zelle graphics.py, tkinter can't read image data

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

I am trying to display the image "picture.gif" in this code:

```
from graphics import *
import tkinter

win = GraphWin("Self Portrait", "1000", "500")
image = Image(Point(5,5), "picture.gif")
image.draw(win)
window.mainloop()
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jstorrke/Desktop/Python/graphicsProject.py", line 6, in <module>
    image = Image(Point(5,5), "picture.gif")
  File "/Users/jstorrke/Desktop/Python/graphics.py", line 827, in __init__
    self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file=pixmap[0], master=_root)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3394, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3350, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "picture.gif"
```

Comment: I know nothing about both frameworks (?) but maybe there is a problem with .gif files? Have you tried some bmp/jpg/png ?

Comment: Please add picture.gif to your question

Comment: picture.gif is a picture of me, so I won't be sharing it.

Comment: I just tried it with another gif and it worked. It must be the picture, then.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics module provides very minimal support for displaying images. Try putting the image on the same folder as where graphics library is and see if it helps.

Please look at this document for more information on graphics module. http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "picture.gif"

I looked at dozens of examples this error message and the cause seems to fall into two categories:

1) The file wasn't a supported type (e.g. *.jpg, *.png, *.tif) which was obvious from the extension.

2) The file used was mislabeld as a *.gif when it wasn't. (More common than I would expect.)  On Unix systems you may be able to use the `file` command to verify your GIF:

```
> file p7Q6O.gif 
p7Q6O.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 520 x 416
>
```

An actual failure of a valid GIF file occurs if it's an animated GIF which are not supported.  However, this can be a silent failure -- no error message and no image displayed.